# Constructible fans

Tags: simplicial-complexes, co.combinatorics

The face poset of a complete simplicial fan is a simplicial sphere. It is not shellable in general, but Kleinschmidt, Smilansky and Onn shown that it is always partitionable. Constructibility is a notion slightly weaker than shellability. Is it known whether a (simplicial complete) fan is constructible or not?